# How to limit a number of snapshots returned by cat snapshot API by Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch has so called [cat snapshot API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-snapshots.html) that returns ALL taken snapshots.

```
http://{elasticsearch}:9200/_cat/snapshots/{repository}
```

I want to automatically check that a snapshot was taken for the last hour using this API.

Is it possible to limit the number of snapshots returned by this API to the last hour or last 10 ?

Comment: as I know there is no such feature in this API. I think you should handle this issue with bash script and linux capability

Comment: @hamidbayat It looks like you are right, there is no such feature there.